# InputStream siempre NULL usando el método getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, archivo

este código me debe de generar 'propertiesStream' de tipo 'InputStream' al pasarle la clase y la ruta del fichero 'InputStream'.

Para asegurarme que la ruta es correcta, lo verifico abriendo el archivo y llamado a su ubicación y si este existe.

La cuestión es que 'propertiesStream' siempre es null. He probado todo lo que se me ha ocurrido, pasar ruta absoluta.....

```
    public class KGGOConnector {

    public static final String configurationPropertiesPath = "conf/Configuration.properties";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    File archivo = new File(KGGOConnector.configurationPropertiesPath);
    WriteLog.debug("el getPath es: " + archivo.getPath());
    WriteLog.debug("el archivo existe?: " + archivo.exists());

    try {

        InputStream propertiesStream = KGGOConnector.class.getResourceAsStream(configurationPropertiesPath);
        WriteLog.debug("propertiesStream: " + propertiesStream);

    } catch (Exception e ) {

        WriteLog.info(e.getMessage());

    }
}
}
```

La salida del código es la siguiente:

```
[el getPath es: conf\Configuration.properties]

[el archivo existe?: true]

[propertiesStream: null]
```

¿Alguien me puede orientar donde está mi error?

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método [Class#getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) se utiliza para buscar recursos en el classpath/modulepath de la aplicación y no en el systema de archivos. Este debe usarse cuando quieres cargar un archivo que sabes que cuando empaquetes la aplicación va a estar dentro de un JAR.

Si ya tienes una instancia de `File` que es correcta (porque te identifica que archivo como existente) solo debes hacer uso del constructor que espera una `File` de la clase [FileInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream-java.io.File-).

```
InputStream propertiesStream = new FileInputStream(configurationPropertiesPath);
```

No obstante es una **MUY** buena práctica usar el `try-with-resources` para manejar streams ya que esto te permite olvidarte de gestionar la liberación de los recursos asociados a este (cerrar el stream) una vez termines de usarlo.

```
try (InputStream propertiesStream = new FileInputStream(configurationPropertiesPath);) {
    // aquí uso la variable propertiesStream
} catch (Exception e) {
    WriteLog.info(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Gracias @E. Betanzos, así funciona en la clase local que es lo primero que estoy probando.

Ahora lo que tengo que hacer y por lo que necesito generar el ImputStream con la clase, es realizar un método en otra clase a la que le paso en la llamada la clase desde la que llamo y la ruta al fichero de propiedades y este método lee el fichero Configuration.properties.

Esto es para poder utilizar este método de carga del fichero de propiedades desde cualquier clase del proyecto.

Gracias.

Comment: @rolling si quieres reutilizar el método que cargue el archivo de configuración NO tienes que replicar este código en cada clase que lo necesites. Crea una clase para manejar la configuración y en esta implementa la carga del fichero de propiedades. Luego en cada clase donde necesites leer una propiedad llamas a dicho método.

Comment: Muchas gracias @E. Betanzos, si eso lo tengo claro pero no me expliqué bien antes, lo que necesito hacer es una API independiente del proyecto actual la cual pueda utilizar desde cualquier proyecto, tanto el actual como futuros. A este método le puedo pasar la clase desde donde se invoca y la ruta al fichero de propiedades. Este método cargará el fichero de propiedades en memoria para poder ser utilizado cuando sea necesario.

Comment: Pero este archivo de configuración va a estar dentro del classpath de la aplicación o en una carpeta independiente?

Comment: En una carpeta independiente. Creo que tengo que utilizar la clase 'ClassLoader'

Comment: Si es en una carpeta independiente debes usar el código que te compartí

Comment: Perfecto, muchísimas gracias!